# ExpressionTree method to Assign MemberInitExpression to property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, expression-trees

I am trying to use expression trees so that I can choose to map across to a DTO using entity framework in much the same way as the Include directive works on a DbSet (part of an open sorce project implementing OData).

The code below represents a test case.

```
Expression<Func<Bar, Bar>> mapBar = b => new Bar { BarInt = b.BarInt, BarString = b.BarString };
Expression<Func<Foo, Foo>> mapFoo = f => new Foo { FooInt = f.FooInt, B = null };

Expression<Func<Foo, Foo>> target = f => new Foo { FooInt = f.FooInt, 
    B = new Bar { 
        BarInt=f.B.BarInt, BarString = f.B.BarString 
    } };
```

note Foo.B was null, and has the mapBar expression inserted.

I have got as far as adding the navigation property using the following ExpressionVisitor

```
public class UpdateExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _oldExpr;
    private readonly Expression _newExpr;
    public UpdateExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression oldExpr, Expression newExpr)
    {
        _oldExpr = oldExpr;
        _newExpr = newExpr;
    }

    protected override MemberAssignment VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node)
    {
        if (node.Member.Name == _oldExpr.Name)
        {
            return node.Update(_newExpr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(node);
        return base.VisitMemberAssignment(node);
    }
}
```

But I cant figure out how to alter the expression `new Bar { BarInt = b.BarInt,...`, to become `new Bar { BarInt = f.B.BarInt,...`

The function will need some kind of ExpressionVisitor like so

```
public class MergingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _oldExpr;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _newProp;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _newParent;
    public MergingVisitor(ParameterExpression oldExpr, ParameterExpression newProp, ParameterExpression newParent)
    {
        _oldExpr = oldExpr;
        _newProp = newProp;
        _newParent = newParent;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression == _oldExpr)
        {
            /*!!what to do here!!*/
            var ma = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(_newProp, node.Member);
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(_newParent, ma.Member);
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
```

and they all need to be linked together with something like

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TMap>> MapNavProperty<T, TMap, U, UMap>(this Expression<Func<T, TMap>> parent, Expression<Func<U, UMap>> nav, string propName)
{
    //concern 1 remap name of prop in nav - not sure if I should do this first
    var parentInitVarName = parent.Parameters[0].Name;
    var parentParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parentInitVarName);
    var propParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), propName);
    var mergeVisitor = new MergingVisitor(nav.Parameters[0], propParam, parentParam);
    var newNavBody = mergeVisitor.Visit(nav.Body); //as MemberExpression;

    //concern 2 replace given property
    var visitor = new UpdateExpressionVisitor(propParam, nav.Body);

    return (Expression<Func<T, TMap>>)visitor.Visit(parent);
}
```

although at present the parentParam will fail in the `Expression.MakeMemberAccess` function as it is of type T (Foo in the above example), rather than type U.

How can I alter the variable name and types in the child property's lamda expression - thank you.

#### Update

The answers from Svick and Ivan Stoev are erudite in explanation and both work perfectly - the (passing) unit tests and code from both answers are up [on GitHub here](https://github.com/mcshaz/SimManager/tree/master/SM.Tests). Thank you so much to both of you - it is a shame I cannot tick 2 answers, so it comes down to Eeny, meeny, miny, moe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var parentParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parentInitVarName);
```

This won't work, parameters in expressions are not identified by name, but by reference. What you need to do is just get the parent's parameter.

---

```
var propParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), propName);
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. `propName` is the name of a property, so you need to use it to create member access expression, not parameter expression.

---

```
public MergingVisitor(ParameterExpression oldExpr, ParameterExpression newProp, ParameterExpression newParent)
```

What you need is to replace one expression (`b`) with another (`f.B`). For that, I would create:

```
public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _oldExpr;
    private readonly Expression _newExpr;

    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression oldExpr, Expression newExpr)
    {
        _oldExpr = oldExpr;
        _newExpr = newExpr;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == _oldExpr)
        {
            return _newExpr;
        }
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

---

```
public UpdateExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression oldExpr, Expression newExpr)
```

It doesn't make any sense for `oldExpr` to be a parameter expression. What you need is just a `string`.

---

```
var visitor = new UpdateExpressionVisitor(propParam, nav.Body);
```

You need to actually use `newNavBody` here.

---

The whole `MapNavProperty()` will now look like this:

```
var parentParam = parent.Parameters.Single();
var propExpression = Expression.Property(parentParam, propName);
var mergeVisitor = new ReplaceVisitor(nav.Parameters.Single(), propExpression);
var newNavBody = mergeVisitor.Visit(nav.Body);

var visitor = new UpdateExpressionVisitor(propName, newNavBody);

return (Expression<Func<T, TMap>>)visitor.Visit(parent);
```

---

With these changes, your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use different helpers:

(1) For replacing parameter

```
static Expression ReplaceParameter(this LambdaExpression lambda, Expression target)
{
    return lambda.Body.ReplaceParameter(lambda.Parameters.Single(), target);
}

static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
{
    return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
}

class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression Source;
    public Expression Target;
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

(2) For replacing member assignment value

```
static Expression ReplaceMemberAssignment(this Expression expression, MemberInfo member, Expression value)
{
    return new MemberAssignmentReplacer { Member = member, Value = value }.Visit(expression);
}

class MemberAssignmentReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public MemberInfo Member;
    public Expression Value;
    protected override MemberAssignment VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node)
    {
        return node.Member == Member ? node.Update(Value) : base.VisitMemberAssignment(node);
    }
}
```

With these helpers, the function in question would be something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TMap>> MapNavProperty<T, TMap, U, UMap>(this Expression<Func<T, TMap>> parent, Expression<Func<U, UMap>> nav, string propName)
{
    var parameter = parent.Parameters[0];
    var body = parent.Body.ReplaceMemberAssignment(
        typeof(TMap).GetProperty(propName),
        nav.ReplaceParameter(Expression.Property(parameter, propName))
    );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TMap>>(body, parameter);
}
```