# Expression.Lambda specify ParameterExpression of sub type

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I want to join some expressions with OrElse, this one:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> extraWhere = x => x.ExtraFields.Any(a => a.Value.Contains(filterText));
```

with this code:

```
var buildWhereColumns = BuildWhereColumns<Customer>(columns, filterText);
var combined = Expression.OrElse(buildWhereColumns.Body, extraWhere.Body);
var paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
var replacerX = new ParameterReplacer(paramX);
var newcombined = replacerX.Visit(combined);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(newcombined, paramX);
```

I get an ArgumentException on the replacerX.Visit because it sees the 'a' in the Any as a Customer. How do I specify the (ParameterExpression?)type of a?

The ParameterReplacer:

```
class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression parameter;

    internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter
        (ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ParameterReplacer` is not a standard class, could you post the implementation of if ? My guess is ParmeterReplacer replaces ALL paramters

Comment: But how it should work? What if `T` is not `Customer` but some other type? Your `extraWhere` seems to be for customer queries only.

Comment: T is Customer sorry yes, I'm already trying something with the ParameterReplacer

Comment: The `ParameterReplacer` used is not a good one (too brute force, blindly replacing *any* parameter). Search SO for better one which allows you to specify *what* to replace - like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681045/expressiontree-method-to-assign-memberinitexpression-to-property/35683423#35683423.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Titian Cernicova-Dragomir I solved it by fixing the ParameterReplacer. I added an extra ParameterExpression:

```
var paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
var paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ExtraFields), "a");
var replacerX = new ParameterReplacer(paramX, paramA);
var newcombined = replacerX.Visit(combined);
```

And the ParameterReplacer

```
class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression[] parameter;

    internal ParameterReplacer(params ParameterExpression[] parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter
        (ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return parameter.Single(x => x.Type == node.Type);
    }
}
```